# Is this probabilistic proof for Brocard's Conjecture flawed?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, solution-verification, square-numbers, conjectures

Brocard's conjecture is the assertion that there are at least four primes between consecutive prime squares, for primes greater than 2. In notation,

$\pi(p_{n+1}^{2})-\pi(p_{n}^{2})\ge4$
for $n\gt1$
(so $p_n\gt2$).

I've been working on Legendre's conjecture for a while, so I figured taking a stab at a weaker form might give me insight to a more 'fertile' method of investigation. Anyway, here's what I have so far, and it feels... incomplete. If you could give it a run down, it would be much appreciated! :)

(Also, I'm sorry my language is a bit complicated - I need to re-study set theory :^)

All $x$ on the open interval $(1,p_{n+1}^{2})$ of the form

$x=(p_{n}\#)\cdot{k}+q$,

where

- $k,q\in{\Bbb{Z_{0}^{+}}}$
- $q\lt{p_{n}\#}$
- and $\gcd(q,p_{n}\#)=1$
- (and $\#$ denotes the *primorial* function)

are prime (Eratosthenes).

As an example, all numbers that are coprime to $30$, which is $2\cdot{3}\cdot{5}$, on the open interval $(1,7^{2})$ are prime: $7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47$. This follows from the Sieve of Eratosthenes, and the fact that a proper divisor $d$ of a number $N$ must be less than or equal to the square root of that number $N$.

The only primes on the open interval $(1,p_{n+1}^{2})$ that are *not* of the form $x=(p_{n}\#)\cdot{k}+q$ are those primes

$p_{C}, C\le{n}$,

because when $k=0,x=q$, so $\gcd(x,p_{n}\#)\ne{1}$ if $x=p_{C}$,

and when $k\gt{0},x=(p_{n}\#)\cdot{k}+q\gt{p_n}\#\gt{p_{C}}$, so $x\ne P_{C}$,

and there are $n$ of these primes.

There are $\phi{(p_{n}\#)}$ $q$'s coprime to $p_{n}\#$, where $\phi{(x)}$ is Euler's totient function, by definition (Euler).
A well known way to calculate the totient of a primorial is by the product

$\phi(p_{n}\#)=p_{n}\#\cdot{\prod\limits_{prime\space{p_i}}^{p_{n}}}{\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)}$

Let $\bar{\phi}(p_{n}\#)$ denote the *proportion of q's over $(1,p_{n}\#)$*, that is:

$\bar{\phi}(p_{n}\#)=\frac{p_{n}\#\cdot{\prod\limits_{prime\space{p_i}}^{p_{n}}}{\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)}}{p_{n}\#}=\prod\limits_{prime\space{p_i}}^{p_{n}}{\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)}=\prod\limits_{prime\space{p_i}}^{p_{n}}{\left(\frac{p_i-1}{p_i}\right)}$

Now, using this proportion $\bar{\phi}$, we can ***estimate*** the number of numbers on $(1,p_{n+1}^{2})$ that are coprime to $p_{n}\#$ and thus prime, like so:

$\left(\bar{\phi}(p_{n}\#)\right)\cdot\left(p_{n+1}^{2}-2\right)$.

This is derived from the proportion $\bar{\phi}$ multiplied by the amount of numbers on the interval, $\left(p_{n+1}^{2}-2\right)$.

And adding back the $n$ first primes $p_{C}$, we have:

$\pi(p_{n+1}^2)\approx{n}+\left(\bar{\phi}(p_{n}\#)\right)\cdot\left(p_{n+1}^{2}-2\right)$. You may see where I'm going with this.

Let's now consider the proportion $\bar{\phi}(p_{n}\#)$:

Reorganizing, $\bar{\phi}(p_{n}\#)=\prod\limits_{prime\space{p_i}}^{p_n}\left(\frac{p_i-1}{p_i}\right)=\frac{1}{p_n}\cdot\prod\limits_{prime\space{p_i}\gt2}^{p_n}\left(\frac{p_i-1}{p_{i-1}}\right)$.

As $p_{n+1}\ge{p_{n}+2}$, so $\prod\limits_{prime\space{p_i}\gt2}^{p_n}\left(\frac{p_i-1}{p_{i-1}}\right)\gt{1}$ for $n>1$, and $\bar{\phi}(p_n\#)\gt{\frac{1}{p_{n}}}\gt{\frac{1}{p_{n+1}}}$

For $n=4$, we have $p_{4}=7$, so

$\bar{\phi}(7\#)=\prod\limits_{prime \space {p_i}}^{7}\frac{p_i-1}{p_i}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{6}{7}=1\cdot\frac{2}{2}\cdot\frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{6}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{7}=\frac{8}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{7}$

More specifically, $\bar{\phi}(p_{n})\ge\frac{8}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{p_{n}}\gt\frac{8}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{p_{n+1}}$ when $n\ge4$.

Rewriting as a recurrence relationship, $\bar{\phi}(p_{n}\#)=\bar{\phi}(p_{n-1}\#)\cdot\frac{p_{n}-1}{p_{n}}$, so $\bar{\phi}(p_{n}\#)\gt\frac{8}{5}\cdot\frac{p_{n}-1}{p_{n}^2}\gt\frac{8}{5}\cdot\frac{p_{n+1}-1}{p_{n+1}^2}$ when $n\gt4$.

Now, finally, let

$A:=\pi(p_{n+1}^2)\approx{n}+\bar{\phi}(p_{n}\#)\cdot{\left(p_{n+1}^2-2\right)}$, and

$B:=\pi(p_{n}^2)\approx{n-1}+\bar{\phi}(p_{n-1}\#)\cdot\left(p_{n}^2-2\right)$.

Restating $A$ using the recurrence relation,

$A\approx{n+\left(\frac{p_n-1}{p_n}\right)\cdot\bar{\phi}(p_{n-1}\#)\cdot\left(p_{n+1}^2-2\right)}$.

Taking the difference, $A-B\approx{1+\bar{\phi}(p_{n-1}\#)\cdot\left[\left(\frac{p_{n}-1}{p_{n}}\right)\cdot\left(p_{n+1}^2-2\right)-\left(p_{n}^2-2\right)\right]}$, and simplifying using $p_{n+1}\ge p_{n}+2$,

$A-B\ge{1+\bar{\phi}(p_{n-1}\#)\cdot\left[\left(\frac{p_{n}-1}{p_{n}}\right)\cdot\left((p_{n}+2)^2-2\right)-\left(p_{n}^2-2\right)\right]}$

Skipping some working out...(I might add a comment with this particular working out)

$A-B\ge{1+\bar{\phi}(p_{n-1}\#)\cdot\left[\frac{3p_{n}^2-2}{p_{n}}\right]}$

And lastly, using the $\bar{\phi}$ inequality,

$A-B\gt{1+\frac{8}{5}\cdot\left(\frac{p_n-1}{p_n^2}\right)\cdot\left[\frac{3p_{n}^2-2}{p_{n}}\right]}=1+\frac{8}{5}\cdot\left(3-\frac{3}{p_{n}}-\frac{2}{p_{n}^2}+\frac{2}{p_{n}^3}\right)\gt4$ when $p_n\gt3$, which agrees with the range of $n\ge4, p_n\ge{7}$ from the $\bar{\phi}$ inequality. The existence of at least four primes between $3^2$ and $5^2$, and at least four more between $5^2$ and $7^2$ can be verified manually $\left[\left(11,13,17,19,23\right),\left(29,31,37,41,43,47\right)\right]$.

Q.E.D.?

Comment: Brocard's conjecture, like Legendre's, is very weak, and any estimate of the number of primes is going to suffice for a heuristic argument in support. But there a difference between a heuristic argument and a proof.

Comment: Your opening hypothesis: $\\ $All $x$ on $(1,p_{n+1}^{2})$ of the form 

$x=(p_{n}\#)\cdot{k}+q$,

where 

 - $k,q\in{\Bbb{Z_{0}^{+}}}$
 - $q\lt{p_{n}\#}$
 - and $\gcd(q,p_{n}\#)=1$
 - (and $\#$ denotes the *primorial* function)

are prime (Eratosthenes). $\\ $ is false. Such numbers are either prime, or have prime factors $>p_n$.

Comment: @KeithBackman No, it's the open interval. The first $x$ to be divisible by a prime factor $>p_n$ and not divisible by any other prime $\le{p_{n}}$ is $p_{n+1}^2$. "A proper factor of a number must be less than or equal to that number's square root".

Comment: I see the problem. I was focused on the fact that $p_n\# +1$ need not be a prime. If you're limiting yourself to the interval $(1,p_{n+1}^2)$, then for $n\ge 4$, there simple are no such numbers, since $p_4=7;\  7\#=210$ but $p_5^2=121$. There are no numbers $x=210k+q$ that fall in the interval $(1,121)$, and the situation gets worse for larger $n$.

Comment: @KeithBackman Please re-read original post thoroughly. $k\ge{0}$

Comment: Any thoughts on Maxim's answer, Sneeze?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Love it, even if I'm dumb :) He mentioned what you mentioned earlier about heuristics being different from a proof. I wish I could've chosen your comment as an answer!

Comment: Well, Sneeze, you could have suggested I trade in my comment for an answer, and I wouold have been happy to oblige. Don't worry about it – all's well that ends well.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use *estimation*, you throw out all rigor in the proof. In fact, your proof does not at all mention the degree of accuracy of your estimation.

There does not seem to be a way to salvage this into a valid proof. After computationally examining your estimate up to $p_{50}$, it turns out that your estimate for $A-B$ is, in some cases, substantially greater than the actual value.

In other words, although $A-B<1+\bar{\phi}(p_{n-1}\#)\cdot\left[\left(\frac{p_{n}-1}{p_{n}}\right)\cdot\left(p_{n+1}^2-2\right)-\left(p_{n}^2-2\right)\right]$ for many primes, you then must show that $A-B$ is greater than something, which is clearly not how inequalities work.

The case where you overestimate $A-B$ does not seem to be rare. For example, such cases occur at $n=50,47,46,44$, to provide some examples.

Comment: Y'know, it seems ridiculous in hindsight to conflate estimation with a "proof". Thank you for pointing out what should have been obvious to me, +1 for that:) As far as the inequality, I thought that I constructed it such that $A-B$ is greater than something, even if it were an estimate, but you stated in your comment that $A-B$ is less than [...]. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm just pointing out that if your initial estimate had always underestimated A-B, the proof would possibly work, but it doesn't.